# Why isn't SublimeText's package development available?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have put the `package control` and `AAAPackageDev` sublime-package files inside the `Installed packages` folder. However, upon trying to create define a new syntax definition I get something that look like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6VMo.jpg)..
Can anyone explain what went wrong? I am using SublimeText3, and I've downloaded the `package control` using this code in the console:
I got the `AAAPackageDev` package from the Git [repo](https://github.com/SublimeText/AAAPackageDev):

```
import urllib.request,os; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; 
ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); 
open(os.path.join(ipp, pf), 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAAPackageDev is not compatible with ST3 (as far as I know). If you specify what you are trying to do, I can try to help more. I looked at the pull requests for AAAPackageDev, it seems there is one for ST3, though I don't know if it's stable or not. You could always try to use that fork rather than the main repo.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but you can probably pull out the components you want from AAAPackageDev and make them ST3 compatible. It's also likely there are packages that have some subset of features of AAAPackageDev. I only think this because I doubt people stopped wanting to develop packages just because ST3 doesn't support AAAPackageDev. Well, in the end, it's up to you. Glad to help.

Comment: **UPDATE** PackageDev (renamed from AAAPackageDev) now fully supports ST3.